# Qual é a diferença entre Webhooks e uma API REST?

Tags: api, rest, http, webhook

Em uma `API REST` definimos um recurso para receber dados e então devolver alguma resposta.
E para enviar uma mensagem para um `webhook`, realizamos uma requisição e também recebemos uma resposta (dependendo do caso).

Ambos fazem a mesma coisa?
Então qual é a diferença? É apenas conceitual ou de implementação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um Webhook é um serviço, API é o conjunto de regras e métodos com que podemos comunicar e usar esse serviço. Há webhooks que usar uma API do tipo REST, outros que usam API customizada, outras GraphQL, Thrift, etc...

Dito ainda de outra maneira:
Webhook é um serviço online, API é a maneira de interagir com o Webhook.

Answer (score 7):

**O que é um WebHook?**

Um WebHook é um endpoint HTTP da qual um cliente deve implementar para receber notificações de eventos que ocorrem em um servidor.

**Ambos fazem a mesma coisa?**

Não. Em uma API REST, o servidor expõe um conjunto de serviços através de endpoints HTTP. Em um WebHook, o cliente expõe um endpoint HTTP e se inscreve no servidor para receber notificações de eventos.

**Então qual é a diferença?**

A diferença é que o cliente consome a API REST do servidor diretamente através de requisições HTTP enquanto que os WebHooks são requisições HTTP das quais o cliente deve aguardar.